# Is there any JVM simulator?

Tags: java, simulation

Is there any JVM simulator online/offline which can actually show the memory usage, GC process, linking, and all other functionality of JVM for the sample Java program?

It can help to understand Java Memory Model and Runtime data areas quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There us [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) which lets you monitor graphically the memory, performance and behaviour of a given JVM - since the JVM is itself a Virtual Machine it is its own best simulator. More information can be found on the [developer site](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Comment: Although I couldn't get the information that I was looking for. But I think it is right answer